# How do I access localhost on https?

Tags: https

I'm trying to set up an OAuth Flow integration with another site and the redirect URL they have set up for me to test the integration is 'https://localhost:3000'. When redirected back to this link, the page doesn't show my localhost, it just gives Google's "This site can’t provide a secure connection" page. Is there a way to access localhost on https? or do I need to ask the integration site to change my redirect URL?

Comment: you can change that HTTPS to HTTP in auth0 console, it will work (yes ask the integration site to change the redirect URL).
There are several ways to access localhost on HTTPS but they are overkill for running a front-end application.

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask them to change it